# StringWithTag Tag value

Tags: java, android, list, listview

This code was taken from a prior post, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the text ("12345") of the tag          NOT the text ("goldman")

```
  public class StringWithTag {
    public String string;
    public Object tag;

    public StringWithTag(String stringPart, Object tagPart) {
        string = stringPart;
        tag = tagPart;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Spinner Part

```
   List<StringWithTag> list = new ArrayList<StringWithTag>();
list.add(new StringWithTag("Goldman", "12345"));
list.add(new StringWithTag("Vampire", "987654"));
list.add(new StringWithTag("Squid", "ABCDEE"));
ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> adap = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

How do I toast the tag value?  can you also provide an example of putting it in a string?  Thank you.

```
**public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parant, View v, int pos, long id) {
    StringWithTag s = (StringWithTag) parant.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    Object tag = s.tag;
}**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following can help

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parant, View v, int pos, long id) {
    StringWithTag s = (StringWithTag) parant.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    Object tag = s.tag;
    if (null != tag && tag instanceof String) {
        // Show toast
        // Toast.makeText(your context, (String) tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```